# How to render a view directly from a method, without returning a View or Response to the calling method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a method in my `BaseController` (simplified here to avoid distraction by unimportant details):

```
protected function handle_empty($report) {
  if (count($report) == 0) {
    return Response::make('Error: that report does not have any data available.', 404, array());
  }
}
```

it is intended to be used in many different controller methods to handle a case where I'm generating a report from JSON, and I've been given JSON without any report data.

I want to be able to use it in (e.g.) my `ScandownController`'s `createHTML()` method (as well as its `createPDF` and `createXL` methods, and all the same methods in all the other controllers for the dozen or so other reports that I have to generate), and I want to do it in one line, preferably like so:

```
$this->handle_empty($report);
```

This (of course!) doesn't work, since the `handle_empty` ***returns*** a `Response`.  Is there anyway I can directly render it from there?  Something analogous to this:

```
protected function handle_empty($report) {
  if (count($report) == 0) {
    # NOTE: *render* instead of *return*:
    render Response::make('Error: that report does not have any data available.', 404, array());
  }
}
```

I don't want to copy and paste an `if`/`then` clause into every report's `createHTML` method, `createPDF` method, and `createXL` method, as that's just a horrible practice.  I have a workaround that allows me to use one line in each of the report-generating methods, but it's ugly and not much better.

```
if ($this->is_defective($report)) { return $this->bail(); }
```

So what's Laravel's of rendering immediately, as opposed to just returning a value to the method that was called by the router?

I tried this (with and without echo), based on what I could find by Googling, and it didn't work:

```
Response::make('blah blah', 404, array())->render();
```

---

***Update***:

I tried to include only detail that is helpful in explaining the problem, and to include all the detail that is helpful, but if all the preceding info doesn't make sense to you, the question boils down to this:

#### How can a helper method (called by the controller action) force a `View` or `Response` to be rendered, without just `return`ing it to the controller action to in turn `return`.

Comment: Why can't your controller action just "return" that call to $this->handle_empty($report) instead of just calling it and doing nothing with the returned response?

Comment: because if the report is good it needs to build the view and return *that*.  The only time I'd want the controller action to return the result of `$this->handle_empty($report)` is when there's a problem.  So in one case I want the `handle_empty()` to determine what gets rendered, and in the other I want the controller action to do that.

Comment: Then simply add an 'else' that returns false from this method so your action can determine what to do from the response.

Answer (score 3):

1. Define new Exception class extending `Exception`. Say, `class YourNameSpace\CustomException extends Exception {}`.
2. Throw  `YourNameSpace\CustomException` from `handle_empty()`

   ```
   protected function handle_empty() {
        if (count($report) == 0) throw new YourNamespace\CustomException;
   }
   ```
3. Handle that exception in App::error. (in `app/start/global`)

   ```
   App::error(function(YourNamespace\CustomException $exception)
   {
        // Handle the exception...
        return Response::make('Error: that report does not have any data available.', 404, array());
   });
   ```

Make sure this comes before `App::error(function(Exception $exception){});` handler.

Comment: Did it work for you? If so please accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark), so that it will be a help to someone in the future.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet... I'm using a work-around at the moment